# Always getting SpatialAnchorManager improperly configured

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

Hi i followed de docs multiple times, but i always recieve the same error in the debug window inside the app.

SpatialAnchorManager improperly configured. Any advice or help? i've set account id, key domain everything. Folled step by step the docs, any thought

Also when the build is finished i get this errors.

[errors after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jiYY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the error is that you have to add these two components to the MixedRealityToolkit:

```
ARSessionOrigin (Script)
ARAnchorManager (Script)
```

Credits to [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bovUKcBoVgk&lc=Ugyrlu5p3PsZVUps7Wl4AaABAg.9KR66XFmFR49KbPU0HBg1P&ab_channel=IvanaTilca) (minute 19:15).

Haven't found any info about this in the documentation but it seems to work.